# Sum multiple columns in one if the columns contain specific words

Tags: excel, vba, loops, sumifs

I want to sum multiple columns that contain the words "SM" in one column. The code return only the values of the last column that contains the words "SM", it dosen't retrun the total. Here is the code :

```
Sub UHD_Values()

Dim i, x As Long

With Sheets("BDD")

LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = 2 To LastRow
For x = 9 To LastCol

If InStr(1, .Cells(x).Value, "SM") Then Sheets("RR").Cells(i, 5) = .Cells(i, x)

Next x, i

End With

End Sub
```

Here is the data :

[image]

Comment: You are overwriting with this bit `Sheets("RR").Cells(i, 5) = .Cells(i, x)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If InStr(1, .Cells(x).Value, "SM") Then Sheets("RR").Cells(i, 5) = .Cells(i, x)
```

should be

```
If InStr(1, .Cells(x).Value, "SM") Then Sheets("RR").Cells(i, 5) = Sheets("RR").Cells(i, 5) +  .Cells(i, x)
```

You were continually overwriting cells(i,x) in each loop

Answer (score 0):

That should work:

```
Sub UHD_Values()

Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long
Dim i As Long, x As Long

With Sheets("BDD")

    lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For i = 2 To lastRow
        For x = 9 To lastCol

            If InStr(1, .Cells(i, x).Value, "SM") > 0 Then
                Sheets("RR").Cells(i, 5) = .Cells(i, x).Value
            End If

        Next x
    Next i

End With

End Sub
```